# Office365 REST API query to add a hyperlink to list? ClientServiceException Cannot deserialize data for type Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUrlValue

Tags: c#, python, rest, sharepoint, office365

I'm using the official Office 365 REST API to retrieve items from lists as well as upload files to Sharepoint and Onedrive https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client/blob/master/examples/sharepoint/listitem_operations.py

I'm currently trying to find a way to include attachments to my Sharepoint list, and what I'm trying to do is to insert a web URL to my list. However because it is a hyperlink type, I get an exception error saying it `Cannot deserialize data for type Microsoft.SharePoint.SPFieldUrlValue.', "500 Server Error: Internal Server Error for url:`

I know that for a direct query it has to look something like:

```
'__metadata': {'type': 'SP.Data.TasksListItem'},
{Url: 'http://google.com', Description: 'This is the description'}
```

Is there any way to more properly format the API query so that I can properly upload the link? Or is there a way to possibly upload the item as text and have it show up in Sharepoint as a clickable hyperlink?

Edit: Just to clarify, this is the function used to update list items:

```
def update_list_item(lst, row_id, column, value):
    print("Update list item example...")
    list_object = ctx.web.lists.get_by_title(lst)
    item_id = str(row_id)
    item = list_object.get_item_by_id(item_id)
    item.set_property(column, str(value))
    item.set_property('Key', 'Value')
    item.update()
    ctx.execute_query()
    print("List item '{0}' has been updated.".format(item_id))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this:

```
    '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.TasksListItem' },
    'Field': 
            {
                '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.FieldUrlValue' },
                'Description': 'This is the description',
                'Url': 'http://google.com'
            }
```

Comment: Is there a way to do this in the documented API however? I don't see the functionality there

Comment: If you want to creat list item, this should work item_properties = '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.Data.TasksListItem' },'Field': { '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.FieldUrlValue' }, 'Description': 'This is the description', 'Url': 'http://google.com'},

Comment: If you want to update list item, may be you could try this: item.set_property('Field', 'http://google.com, This is the description').

Comment: unfortunately I am getting the same exact error, cannot deserialize data. Not sure if there is a specific syntax issue with this or if I'm able to create my own function within the API library to solve this?